# unable to find enumerate() func in Swift standard library reference

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumerate

I'm new to Swift and is learning the concept of Array. I saw the code below from "swift programming language 2.1".

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {
    print("\(value) at index \(index)")
}
```

I want to read a bit more about the `enumerate()` func so I looked up the [Apple developer's page on Array](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Array_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/struct/s:Sa), however, I could not find a func named `enumerate()` on this page. Am I looking at the wrong place or is there something I am missing? Coudl someone please give me a hand? Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you encounter a Swift standard library function or method that you can't find documentation on, command-click on it in Xcode. That will take you to its definition, which in this case is

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Return a lazy `SequenceType` containing pairs (*n*, *x*), where
    /// *n*s are consecutive `Int`s starting at zero, and *x*s are
    /// the elements of `base`:
    ///
    ///     > for (n, c) in "Swift".characters.enumerate() {
    ///         print("\(n): '\(c)'")
    ///       }
    ///     0: 'S'
    ///     1: 'w'
    ///     2: 'i'
    ///     3: 'f'
    ///     4: 't'
    @warn_unused_result
    public func enumerate() -> EnumerateSequence<Self>
}
```

What the above states is that `enumerate()` gives you back a tuple for each value in your collection, with the first element in the tuple being the index of the current item and the second being the value of that item.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip! btw, do you mind if I ask, why there are certain function or method not included in the documentation?

Comment: The `enumerate` method [is defined by `SequenceType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceType_SsS_9enumerateuRq_S__Fq_FT_GVSs17EnumerateSequenceq__), a protocol that `Array` adopts (indirectly, by way of adopting `CollectionType`). The Apple docs for a type don't show all the methods it gains through superclasses or protocol conformance, so to see all the methods on a type you have to click through the "Inherits from" and "Conforms to" links.